# Handle Automapper exception?

Tags: c#, try-catch, automapper, asp.net-mvc-5

Using mvc5 with automapper I have following:

In Controller :

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LunchMenu_Create_Index(VmSysMenuCreate menu)
        {
            try
            {
                var domainMenu = Mapper.Map<VmSysMenuCreate, Menu>(menu);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content("Error msg");
            }

            return Content("Succes");
        }
```

Mapping:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<VmSysMenuCreate, Menu>()
                .ForMember(c => c.Id, op => op.MapFrom(v => v.Id))
                .ForMember(c => c.MenuDate, op => op.ResolveUsing(data =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DateTime convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data);
                        return convertedDate;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw new Exception("Date not in correct format", ex);
                    }

                }));
```

Doing this I was excpected to catch automapper error when tryng to map my objects , but this 
is not working like I was expect.

How can I catch error in controller that is thrown from automapper?
If you have any question please ask me..
Thanks for you attention!

Comment: So what *does* happen when `Mapper.Map` throws an exception?

Comment: Project stop at first throw in automapper not in controller...

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice. Why don't you just return NULL (assuming Nullable<DateTime>) in such case, and do the validation in a business layer?

Comment: This is just an example ,I didn't ask how to do it...I just need to catch exception...

Comment: It looks like you want to use a validation framework, not catch specific exceptions. But your catch will still work as expected, you're just not interpreting the debugger correctly. Your catch still happens in the controller but you incorrectly think that it shouldn't break on the catch in the ResolveUsing statement. I bet if you hit F5 the catch would hit in your controller after the ResolveUsing part.

Comment: ohhh, I can't get it to work :( , after pressing F5 it error is not cached in controller.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but probably you have the option CLR Exceptions Thrown ON.

Select "Exceptions..." from "Debug" menu. (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)

[image]

If the highlighted Thrown option is ON, you'll see the debugger stopping in the innermost exception.

Comment: Why this will help me?I just want to catch exception thrown by automapper and handle it in controller , why this will help me? :D

Comment: You said "Project stop at first throw in automapper not in controller". What do you mean by "Project stop" ?

Comment: This could be because the debugger is _breaking_ on the inner-most exception. Can you try without debugger attached?

Comment: If you can't try I can't help you. I don't know if this is related, but _NullReferenceException_ are swallowed by design: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/o5NyuVhAfzw. Good luck.

Comment: Just an FYI, those aren't swallowed any more as of 3.1.