# Automapper handling custom made exceptions so can't handle them elsewhere

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I am throwing custom exceptions inside my resolvers, but they are being caught and wrapped by Automapper so we cant handle them elsewhere in the program. I've included a simple example of the problem, the desired outcome is to catch an InterfaceError but it only catches an AutoMapperException with the InterfaceError as an inner exception.

In class:

```
public Order MapOrder(InterfaceOrder iOrder)
{
    try
    {
        Order mappedOrder = Mapper.Map<InterfaceOrder, Order>(iOrder);
    }
    catch (InterfaceException ex)
    {
        Log("Interface error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Log("error");  
    }

    return mappedOrder;
}
```

Mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<InterfaceOrder, Order>()                
      .ForMember(c => c.Name, op => op.ResolveUsing(data =>
        {
            if (Name.Length > 50) 
            { 
                throw new InterfaceException("Error!", ex);                                                                   
            }
            else 
            {
                return c.Name
            }
        }));
```

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350603/handle-automapper-exception

Comment: I saw your question but I felt mine is different in the sense that I'm not having a problem catching the exception, my problem is that the exception caught is an AutoMapper exception with the InterfaceException as an inner exception. I want to just catch the InterfaceException. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Automapper doesn't let an exception escape directly from the mapping process, but tries and wrap it in its own Exception as you noticed. Your best bet would be to wrap the call to Map inside a function that catches `AutoMapperMappingException` and unwrap it

```
public ToClass Map<FromClass, ToClass>(FromClass fc)
{
    try
    {
        return Mapper.Map<FromClass, ToClass>(fc);
    }
    catch(AutoMapperMappingException autoMapperException)
    {
        throw autoMapperException.InnerException; 
        // this will break your call stack
        // you may not know where the error is called and rather
        // want to clone the InnerException or throw a brand new Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. InnerException is still "AutoMapperMappingException", not my custom exception

Comment: Ok, fixed it. It should be `autoMapperException.InnerException.InnerException`

Answer (score 1):

An interesting note.
The wrapping of the exception only happens, if it is thrown from `ForMember(...MapFrom(...))` call. If the same exception is thrown in `AfterMap(...)`, it is not wrapped.

Comment: For the sake of completness, `BeforeMap()` works too. Useful for precondition checks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from @Emaro I tried with BeforeMap()

```
public AgentMapper()
{
CreateMap<AgentDto,Agent> ().BeforeMap((src, dest) => CheckTypeExits(src.Ty))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomResolverEnumToInt, string>(src => src.Type))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Settings, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Settings));
}

///Checks if the type exists in enum if now will throw a bad request which was handled using a custom exception filter
public void CheckTypeExits(dynamic source)
{
var type= typeof(int) == source.GetType() ? source : source.Replace(" ", "_");
bool enumExists = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(typeEnum), type);
if (!enumExists)
        {
           throw new BadHttpRequestException(Resource.getMessage(nameof(Resource.ERP_TYPE_DOES_NOT_EXIST), new List<string>() { source }));
        }
}

///Function is to convert int to string enum values
public class CustomResolverEnumToInt : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, string, int>
{
       public int Resolve(object source, object destination, string sourceMember, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
      {
           var erpType = sourceMember.Replace(" ", "_");
           return (int)(ERPTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(ERPTypeEnum), erpType);
      }
}
```

BeforeMap() worked fine for me.