# Throw custom error when a mapping error occurs with Automapper in a ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project and I am using AutoMapper. This is how I am configuring it in my `Startup` class:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Is there a way to configure AutoMapper to throw a custom exception when 2 types cannot be mapped? I have more than 10 mapping profiles in my project and I would like a certain error to be thrown when the types cannot be mapped.

I am using .NET 6.0

Comment: Automapper doesn't let an exception escape directly from the mapping process,but you could try and wrap it in its own Exception follow this issue :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409895/automapper-handling-custom-made-exceptions-so-cant-handle-them-elsewhere

Comment: I mentioned that I have more mapping profiles in the project and I am mapping in many places, so I would prefer a solution where I configure this exception in one place

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper throws an AutoMapperMappingException on missed mapping errors.

You can a use middleware to handle the exceptions of type AutoMapperMappingException and do any on it and return specific messages when this error rises.